# Function is not getting triggered while populating field through HTMLUNIT

Tags: htmlunit

I am facing a issue. In which I am trying to populate one of the GUI field as 'Y'(select from'Y'/'N') which results a callback function to be triggered . After the callback function is triggered , one of the disabled field gets enabled. But when I am trying to do this through HTMLUNIT the desired text fields are not getting enabled. I am searching for a way through which I can trigger that callback function from HTMLUNIT. I am using htmlunit 2.17.

Below is the field html tag ..

Partial Port including current BTN

```
                      <br/>
                      <div id="ctl00_ctl00_tabs_OrderPlaceHolder_ctl00_lovPartialPortInclBTN" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Windows7" style="font-weight:normal;width:200px;">
                                <input name="ctl00$ctl00$tabs$OrderPlaceHolder$ctl00$lovPartialPortInclBTN" type="text" class="rcbInput rfdDecorated" id="ctl00_ctl00_tabs_OrderPlaceHolder_ctl00_lovPartialPortInclBTN_Input" value="Y" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off"/>
                                    <div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index:6000;">
                          <div id="ctl00_ctl00_tabs_OrderPlaceHolder_ctl00_lovPartialPortInclBTN_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Windows7 " style="display:none;">
                            <div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width:100%;">
                              <ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
                                <li class="rcbItem ">
                                  N 
                                </li>
                                <li class="rcbItem ">
                                  Y 
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <input id="ctl00_ctl00_tabs_OrderPlaceHolder_ctl00_lovPartialPortInclBTN_ClientState" name="ctl00_ctl00_tabs_OrderPlaceHolder_ctl00_lovPartialPortInclBTN_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;logEntries&quot;:[],&quot;value&quot;:&quot;N&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;N&quot;,&quot;enabled&quot;:true}"/>
                      </div>
```

Below is the callback function which trigger for ID ::

ctl00_ctl00_tabs_OrderPlaceHolder_ctl00_lovPartialPortInclBTN_ClientState

Sys.Application.add_init(function() { 
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox, {"_dropDownWidth":0,"_height":0,"_isAspNet35":true,"_postBackReference":"__doPostBack(\u0027ctl00$ctl00$tabs$OrderPlaceHolder$ctl00$lovPartialPortInclBTN\u0027,\u0027arguments\u0027)","_skin":"Windows7","_text":"N","_uniqueId":"ctl00$ctl00$tabs$OrderPlaceHolder$ctl00$lovPartialPortInclBTN","_value":"N","clientStateFieldID":"ctl00_ctl00_tabs_OrderPlaceHolder_ctl00_lovPartialPortInclBTN_ClientState","collapseAnimation":"{\"duration\":450}","expandAnimation":"{\"duration\":450}","itemData":[{"value":"N","selected":true},{"value":"Y"}],"selectedIndex":0}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ctl00_tabs_OrderPlaceHolder_ctl00_lovPartialPortInclBTN")); 
});

Comment: Any public page where i can try to reproduce your problem and can you show your java code. Do you get any Javascript error?

Comment: No , we don't have any public page . Also we didn't get any java script error.Below is java code which we use now.
 

 HtmlHiddenInput testinput1 = (HtmlHiddenInput) currentPage.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_tabs_OrderPlaceHolder_ctl00_lovPartialPortInclBTN_ClientState")                        testinput1.setValueAttribute("{\"logEntries\":[],\"value\":\"Y\",\"text\":\"Y\",\"enabled\":true}");

Comment: But you are using a telerik control. Usually there is a demo page that shows the various features to this fancy controls. Maybe you can prepare some sample based on this.

Comment: I think your approach is a bit optimistic. Why do you expect that changing the value attribute of the hidden field will trigger anything. Usually these kind of fancy controls are doing a lot of magic as reaction to user input. Maybe there are some handlers associated with the surrounding div's etc.

Comment: And please ask yourself if you like to help someone that posts the code samples in the way you have done (without any formatting, strange escaping).